# nginx different authentication for different directories

Tags: authentication, nginx, bitbucket

finding alternative of htaccess in apache for nginx, want to add different authentication rules for different directories. Different .htpasswd files for different directories. how to do it? Just like bitbucket does, it runs on nginx too.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure that the authentication within BitBucket is handled by the application, there's no `.htpasswd` files anywhere to be found, authentication isn't handled by the web server.

However you can configure nginx to use a different `.htpasswd` for different paths using different location blocks for each path

```
location / {
        root /var/www/app/;
        index index.html index.php;
        auth_basic_user_file /var/www/app/.htpasswd;  
}
location /pathA {
            root /var/www/app/pathA;
            index index.html index.php;
            auth_basic_user_file /var/www/app/pathA/.htpasswd;  
}
```

or something to that effect